# KML Boundary data, tools to create / merge polygons

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml, boundary

I need to make up boundaries for a Google Maps mash-up.

I am trying to find boundary data for London - north, east, west and central.

Searching for hours I only found data for boroughs or postcodes.

Whats the best way of merging postcode boundaries into one polygon?

That way I can take all the London N, NW postcodes and merge them as a London North Polygon, then do the same for East West, South and Central.

Are there any tools (free if possible) where I can do this?

### EDIT

This was marked as a duplicate question, but there is not an answer marked correct - just one answer that is a bit ambiguous about how exactly to merge the polygons using dictionaries & graphs and does not really make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal ends up being to merge a bunch of polygons you already have (regions, city blocks, whatever) into a single polygon any GIS tool will allow you to do this (ESRI ArcGIS offers a trial). I also looks like http://www.gadm.org/ might have you data in the detail you are requesting: Click on:

1. Download by Country
2. Select United Kingdom and KMZ then hit ok
3. Choose level 2 data in the bottom right of the map

Comment: Thanks for that, will download the data and look at it, i was looking at Global mapper, seems like it might be a good investment.i will check out the tools you sugguested too.